# add sdk c++ headers into swift package manager project

Tags: swift-package-manager

I have a c++ project that i want to add to a swift package manager project
the c++ project references headers such as `#include <string>` this header resides in
iossdk/usr/include/c++/v1

how do i get the swift package manager to include those headers ?

````
let package = Package(
    name: "LibProject",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v13)],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "LibProject",
            targets: ["LibModule1", "LibModule2Framework"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "LibModule1",
            path: "Sources/LibModule1"),
        .target(
            name: "LibModule2Framework",
            path: "Sources/LibModule2Framework",
            publicHeadersPath: ".",
            
            cxxSettings: [
                 .headerSearchPath("usr/include/c++/v1"),
            ]
            ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "LibModuleTests",
            dependencies: ["LibModuleTests"]),
    ],
    cLanguageStandard: .c17,
    cxxLanguageStandard: .gnucxx17
)```
````